# How to set a maximum value for `ion-range`?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have the following `ion-range` component.

I set the minimum and maximum values to `0` and `120` respectively.

But also I want to restrict the movement of the thumb to a lower value than `120` (upper limit), for example: `85` but keeping the previous limits: `0` and `120`.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-range min="0" max="120" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="myValue"></ion-range>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Example:

[image]

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered this same issue and have a quick fix!

You can add the `ionChange` event to the `ion-range` component and call a function to update the range's current value. This will fire the function every time the range value is changed but only changes the current value when a logical statement is matched.

**IMPORTANT**: Interestingly, for single knob ranges, you will also need to set the `debounce` attribute to a *positive nonzero number* (the default is 0). This tells how long Ionic should wait before firing the `ionChange` event. When `debounce` = 0, the value assigned to the variable that holds the value (i.e. `myValue`) changes when a function is called, however, visual changes to the range position will not occur for only single knob ranges (it works fine with dual knob ranges). This is a bug the Ionic team should look into.

For example, add the `ionChange` event and `debounce` attribute in your `.html` file:

```
<ion-range min="0" max="120" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="myValue" (ionChange)="restrictValue()" debounce="1"></ion-range>
```

and add a function, `restrictValue()` in this case, in your `.ts` file:

```
restrictValue () {
  if (this.myValue >= 85) {
    this.myValue = 85;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!