# Synchronization two ionic-range

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following two ion-range components.

I set the minimum and maximum values to 0 and 100 respectively.

But also I want to restrict the movement of the thumb in order Start couldn't be greater than Stop

[image]

Comment: so dualKnob is not an option for you? how will user know these ranges are "connected"?

Comment: I added some labels for ranges. What I'm thinking about is that 'Moisture start value' cannot be greater than 'Stop moisture value' and the ion-range pin should get freeze to the other range value. I tried this solution, but unfortunately values get changed but ion-range UI doesen't.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090893/9069543

Comment: sorry I was asking why dual knob range won't suit your UX? thanks for adding detail though;)

Comment: I have been trying the same as you and I have also landed to the same question as you. There is said that Ionic has a kind-of-a-bug, so the pointer never freezes where it should. I tried to add a delay to the `restrictValue()`, no success. Have tried with `dualKnobs="true"`, no success. Both things together, no success. It looks like there is no way. If I were you, I would build my own `ion-range` and fix it to behave the way you want it. You can peek the structure in the inspector. I have build my own seekbars before and is not so difficult.